# What is the best object to string XML serialization API for Java 1.4?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

I want to generate a XML String for a given object. What is the best API to serialize an object to XML String using Java 1.4?

Thanks,

RT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XStream is pretty good for that. They're website is [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Comment: I am testing it now and seems to be great. Thanks :)